# ios core data predicate search for word similar

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Im using coredata in my app,

I can search all entities with a starting letter,

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name MATCHES '^[hH].*'"];
//sort descriptor!
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *companyProducts = [Company allWithPredicate:predicate sortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
Company *theCompany;
NSLog(@"tus companies number:: %d", companyProducts.count);
for (theCompany in companyProducts) {
    NSLog(@"tus companies:: %@", theCompany.name);
}
```

so in this case I will get all companies starting with h no matter lower or upper case...

but if I need to search for matches with more than one letter? no matter lower or upper case,

for example to look for:

Hyper
hyosung

So I need to know how to construct my regex? to have a search for n number of charaters on my properties?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try with BEGINSWITH

Comment: hi @Anupdas I tried with     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name BEGINSWITH 'H'"];
 but the problem is how to make it work with lower case or combination of lower and upper? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name BEGINSWITH [c] %@",@"H"];
```

Comment: hi thanks works great!, will accept when allowed!, but another question, is this regex? so I learn how to construct this predicates? tnx!

Comment: @MaKo Sorry I'm not sure about how they are achieving this. But you can the refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) for more available options in NSPredicate